# Good results with NN, not with SVM; cause for concern?

Tags: neural-network, svm

I have painstakingly gathered data for a proof-of-concept study I am performing. The data consists of 40 different subjects, each with 12 parameters measured at 60 time intervals and 1 output parameter being 0 or 1. So I am building a binary classifier.

I knew beforehand that there is a non-linear relation between the input-parameters and the output so a simple perceptron of Bayes classifier would be unable to classify the sample. This assumption proved correct after initial tests.

Therefore I went to neural networks and as I hoped the results were pretty good. An error of about 1-5% is generally the result. The training is done by using 70% as training and 30% as evaluation. Running the complete dataset again (100%) through the model I was very happy with the results. The following is a typical confusion matrix (P = positive, N = negative):

```
    P    N
P  13    2   
N   3   42
```

So I am happy and with the notion that I used a 30% for evaluation I am confident that I am not fitting noise.

Therefore I resolved to SVM for a double check and the SVM was unable to converge to a good solution. Most of the time the solutions are terrible (say 90% error...). Maybe I am not fully aware of SVM's or the implementations are not correct, but it troubles me because I thought that when NN provide a good solution, SVM's are most of the time better in seperating the data due to their maximum-margin hyperplane.

What does this say of my result? Am I fitting noise? And how do I know if this is a correct result?

I am using Encog for the calculations but the NN results are comparable to home-grown NN models I made.

Comment: May I ask which kernel and parameters are you using for SVM? A huge difference like that between NN and SVM is very unusual. SVM is not necessarily better (depends heavily on the kernel used) but there should be, in any case, a kernel that would produce a comparable result with ANN (sometimes better sometimes worse)

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to mention you so you would be notified. Still getting used to this stackoverflow thing :) @avanwieringen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your first time to use SVM, I strongly recommend you to take a look at [A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classication](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf), by authors of a famous SVM package [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). It gives a list of suggestions to train your SVM classifier.

- Transform data to the format of an SVM package
- Conduct simple scaling on the data
- Consider the RBF kernel
- Use cross-validation to nd the best parameter C and γ
- Use the best parameter C and γ
- to train the whole training set
- Test

In short, try scaling your data and carefully choosing the kernal plus the parameters.

Comment: I read it and it was really helpful. I was able to properly train my model to results comparable with NN.